# RoR: How to retain underscore from URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to get a parameter from the URL and subsequently call a function using that parameter. But the issue is that the parameter sometimes contains an `_` character, which gets skipped and wrong parameter is passed to the function.

Say my url is `localhost:3000/deal/diamond_deal`. I get the parameter as

```
q= params[:promo]
```

But on doing so, q is set to `diamond deal` and not `diamond_deal`. How can work around this issue, please can someone help?

Thanks

**EDIT**: 1. Route for the URl: `match "/deal/:promo" => "deal#index", :as => "deal"`
          2. Rails version: Rails 3.1.10

Comment: That doesn't seem like normal behavior for params. What's your route for that URL?

Comment: @depa : `match "/deal/:promo' => "deal#index", :as => "deal"`

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Also, it's better if you edit your question to include the additional information rather than responding with a comment.

Comment: @depa : i am using rails 3.1.10

Comment: Your route seems to have unmatching quotes (double with single). Is that a typo? Also, shouldn't your controller be named in the plural as in `deals#index`?

Comment: @depa: Ya sorry its a typo. I am using single quotes throughout in my app.

Comment: Have you tried to use `%5F` instead of `_`?

Comment: @AdolAurion : Just checked. Same result.

Comment: So just use a weird character `%F7` which is `÷` and change it to `_` in the controller.

Comment: @AdolAurion : This gives me `ERROR ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

Comment: @nish Use another character... I'm looking for some way to disable rails' parse, but using that technique could be good for you now.

Comment: @AdolAurion: Yes, good idea. I tried using `-` in the URL and replaced it by `_` using gsub. It worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted solution (in comments) was using `-` instead of `_` and replace `-` to `_` in the controller.